# Post data from Excel to IBM - FieldPlus and FieldMinus

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA to post data from Excel to IBM Terminal Form.

The script is only using this `ControlKeyCode_Transmit` function to put the data into each IBM Form field. I'm not sure how, because two of the fields (the Qty and the Amt) require a `FieldPlus` or `FieldMinus` function to exit the field during manual posting.

```vb
ThisIbmScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_Transmit)
```

#1) How would evaluate if the Excel value for those two fields are a positive or negative number?
#2) How do I incorporate the `ControlKeyCode_FieldPlus` or `ControlKeyCode_FieldMinus` functions for only those two fields.

My code with the `ControlKeyCode_Transmit`, working only for positive values.

```vb
Sub GetDataFromExcel_v11()
    Dim path As String
    Dim rCode As ReturnCode
    Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
    Dim wsData As String
    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    Dim wkBook As Object
    Dim x As Integer

    'NOTE Version 11
    
    'NOTE this version uses SIX spreadsheet fields/columns (Ent, Pat#, Chg#, Qty, Amt, Date)
    
    '**SET** the path and the Excel file name (the first one will work from your C:drive "Documents" folder)
    path = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\" & "MS4 VBA Data from Excel Test.xlsx"
    'path = "\\ccal-nas-001b\dept\gssarevint\SSA RI MS4 Admin\MS4 VBA\MS4 VBA Data from Excel Test.xlsx"
        
    'NOTE This tells the Macro to use Excel
    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                           
    ExcelApp.Visible = True
 
    '**SET** the Excel sheet name. This will activate the Excel workbook sheet.
    Set wkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(path)
    wkBook.Sheets("excel charge data").Activate
 
    '**SET** the sheet Row to start on
    row = 2
 
    'NOTE Loop until the Excel row is empty
    Do
            
        'NOTE This is used to clear the fields 1 through 6
        For x = 1 To 6
            ThisIbmScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_FieldPlus)
        Next
        'NOTE Copy Data from Excel (Ent)
        wsData = wkBook.Sheets("excel charge data").cells(row, (col + 1)).value
        'NOTE Put text into field
        rCode = ThisIbmScreen.PutText2(wsData, 19, 13)
            
        'NOTE Copy Data from Excel (Pat#)
        wsData = wkBook.Sheets("excel charge data").cells(row, (col + 2)).value
        'NOTE Put text into field
        rCode = ThisIbmScreen.PutText2(wsData, 19, 24)
           
        'NOTE Copy Data from Excel (Chg#)
        wsData = wkBook.Sheets("excel charge data").cells(row, (col + 3)).value
        'NOTE Put text into field
        rCode = ThisIbmScreen.PutText2(wsData, 19, 41)
            
        'NOTE Copy Data from Excel (Qty)
        wsData = wkBook.Sheets("excel charge data").cells(row, (col + 4)).value
        'NOTE Put text into field
        rCode = ThisIbmScreen.PutText2(wsData, 19, 53)

        'NOTE Copy Data from Excel (Amt)
        wsData = wkBook.Sheets("excel charge data").cells(row, (col + 5)).value
        'NOTE Put text into field
        rCode = ThisIbmScreen.PutText2(wsData, 19, 64)
                   
        'NOTE Copy Data from Excel (Date)
        wsData = wkBook.Sheets("excel charge data").cells(row, (col + 6)).value
        'NOTE Put text into field
        rCode = ThisIbmScreen.PutText2(wsData, 20, 14)
    
        ThisIbmScreen.PutText2 "autoexec", 2, 15

        'NOTE This presses Enter and Field Exit
        ThisIbmScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_Transmit)

        'NOTE Wait for the screen to be ready for input
        rCode = ThisIbmScreen.WaitForHostSettle(1000, 1000)
  
        'NOTE Go to the next row in Excel
        row = row + 1
            
        'NOTE Wait for the screen to be ready for input
        rCode = ThisIbmScreen.WaitForHostSettle(1000, 1000)
         
        'NOTE get the value of the first cell in the row so we can check for an empty row
        wsData = wkBook.Sheets("excel charge data").cells(row, 2).value
              
    Loop While wsData <> ""
    
    MsgBox ("                Custom Macro by Ron Maltase  " & vbCrLf & "     " & vbCrLf & _
            "           ***  MS4 Charge Batch From Excel  ***   " & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & _
            "           _______________________________________   " & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & _
            "                           Macro has finished !")

End Sub
```

The code is working for positive numbers, but not for negative numbers.

I tried replacing

```vb
ThisIbmScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_Transmit)
```

with

```vb
ThisIbmScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_FieldMinus)
```

and with

```vb
ThisIbmScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_FieldPlus)
```